# How to identify anomalous data automatically

Tags: python, data-cleaning

I'm looking to remove anomalous data from a dataset in python and as per comments below, I believe the best way to do this is to have a rolling average - and then remove data if it falls 2-3 std outside of that rolling average.

So far I have the below but it doesn't seem to be doing what I want it to as the errors are still in the dataset

```
def remove_outliers_rolling_dataframe(dataframe, window_size=10, num_std_dev=1):
   
    rolling_avg = dataframe.rolling(window=window_size, min_periods=1).mean()
    std_dev = dataframe.rolling(window=window_size, min_periods=1).std()
    
    lower_bound = rolling_avg - (num_std_dev * std_dev)
    upper_bound = rolling_avg + (num_std_dev * std_dev)
    
    mask = (dataframe >= lower_bound) & (dataframe <= upper_bound)
    
    cleaned_dataframe = dataframe[mask]
    
    return cleaned_dataframe
```

The above makes sense to me but it isn't picking out the data entry errors like I would hope.

The original data looks like this as an example:

[image]

[image]

Comment: "IQR or standard deviations simply don't work as the anomalies are simply data entry errors." Can you expand on this? Why don't they work? And what about std over a rolling window? Judging by your data sample (assuming we see one anomaly around 2018) it should easily solve the problem.

Comment: As you have a long serie of data, you should window IQR over 1 sliding year or 1 sliding month so IQR works on the smaller scale. Or maybee just remove or replace Null / 0 data. Please show working code so we can look and help. see [MRE].

Comment: I would just do a rolling window using std like @YevhenKuzmovych suggested. If you are looking to automatically detect data entry errors thats nearly impossible since without looking deeper you cannot differentiate between a real outlier and an entry error. But that will show you which entries need to be looked at.

Comment: ah I hadn't thought about a rolling window, thank you very much

Comment: I will edit the post to ask about the coding of this - many thanks.

Comment: uploading your data for everyone to have access to would help your case a bit

Comment: @TinoD I don't believe I can add attachments? Happy to do so if you let me know how.

Comment: to a google drive and then post a link here? possibly also with dropbox

Comment: You probably are looking for one class classification algorithms for anomaly detection. The simplest (and quite efficient) is one class SVM: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.OneClassSVM.html